# D3.js bilevel partition won't work in visual studio

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371

Ouside visual studio it will work, but when I use it in visual studio it's shows nothing. 
Has anyone else had this problem or know how to solve it?

Comment: How are you running it ?

Comment: It's a MVC project or what do you mean?

Comment: Thats what I mean yes. Does your vis work in edge ? As that's what the MVC ill be built on

Comment: Yes it works also on edge